# React-Router-Dom Link changes position of my button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components

I have my custom css made button centered using flex in my parent container, when I wrap the button in the React-Router-Dom Link it moves to the right side of the screen.

Anyone know a quick fix for this, found alot of stack overflow posts about getting rid of text-decoration that React-Router-Dom Link adds and tried to apply these workarounds but in terms of getting rid of any potential margin or padding but did not help.

Will be making a code sandbox and posting link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-rain-958y5?file=/src/App.js)

- Also just a sidenote, the scroll bars are activated even though in my project on my localhost they aren't and should not be. Can anyone explain why this is happening?
- And for reference this design is atm developed mobile first and I have not done the media queries for tablet or desktop yet

ProLandingPage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Container from '../LandingPageComponents/Container';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import image from '../Assets/foodImage.jpg'
import  {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export const ProLandingPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <TopBar/>
                <MenuButtonText>
                    Menu
                </MenuButtonText>
                <ContactButtonText>
                    Contact
                </ContactButtonText>
                <Title>
                    Authentic Asian Cuisine Delivered Straight To Your Door!
                </Title>
                <Image/>
                <Subtitle>
                    Cuisines spanning China, Japan and South East Asia...
                </Subtitle>
                <Link to="/menu">
                    <Button type="button">
                        <ButtonText>
                            Order Now!
                        </ButtonText>
                    </Button>
                </Link>


            </Container>
            
        </div>
    )
}



const TopBar = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #161616;
`
const BottomBar = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    
`

const Image = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 171.45px;
    height: 296px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 27%;

    background-image: url(${image});
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 46px;
    transform: rotate(-89.85deg);

    @media (max-width: 281px){
        width: 150px;
        height: 250px;
        top: 30%;
    }
`
const Title = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 168px;
  
    top: 17%;

    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 36px;
    /* or 150% */

    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
`
const Subtitle = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 255px;
    height: 78px;
    
    top: 65.5%;

    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 167% */

    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;

    @media (max-height: 601px){
        top: 70%;
    }
`
const Button = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* left: 28%; */
    width: 178px;
    height: 48px;
    top: 78%;
    
    background: #161616;
    border-radius: 25px;

    @media (max-height: 601px){
        top: 83%;
    }
`

const ButtonText = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;

    color: #F9F9F9;
`
const MenuButtonText = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 126px;
    height: 42px;
    left: 20%;
    top: 23px;

    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 40px;
    /* or 250% */

    text-align: center;

    color: #F9F9F9;

    @media (max-width: 281px){
        left: 10%;
    }
`
const ContactButtonText = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 126px;
    height: 42px;
    right: 20%;
    top: 23px;

    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 40px;
    /* or 250% */

    text-align: center;

    color: #F9F9F9;

    @media (max-width: 281px){
        right: 10%;
    }

`
```

Comment: Your codesandbox is in default state

Comment: Thats so annoying this always happens! I pressed the fork button that should save it right? also it autosaves dont know why this keep happening

Comment: Link works for me , where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I would suggest to inspect in the browser and see the styles. I think the button position absolute is effecting something. Link has nothing related to it

Comment: Why not just add styles to the Link?

Comment: like @moshfiqrony said, button position absolute means its positioning off of the relative position of the HTML element of the Link. If you add styles to the link or change the position of the button, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @moshfiqrony Thanks for taking time to look at this, however position has always been absolute and it was centered fine. Only once I wrapped it in a <Link> did it put the positioning off to the right.

Comment: @sloont I applied styles to the Link like I described on the post however it does not change the position of it - I  can just for example add left:30% to the original button css however I don't want this I would much rather be able to centre it true to the centre like it was before as once I write media queries it will always be centred rather than me having to adjust the left percentage for every width

Comment: I am still can't see the sandbox

Comment: One second Mosh I will try and get it working my apologies

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/gjse9of this should work!

Comment: ok i'm looking at the codesandbox now. how did you attempt to style the Link?

Comment: with styled components: const StyledLink = styled(Link)``

Comment: woops pressed enter.... const StyledLink = styled(Link)`  margin: 0, padding: 0`

Comment: that was what a previous stack overflow post answer stated worked for getting rid of default link attributes

Comment: I updated my answer, I would attempt that method. The problem is, your ```<a>``` tag is floating in the middle of the page with no dimensions, and the button position is based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the link like this

```
<Link style={{ width: "100%", display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }} to="/menu">
  <Button type="button">
    <ButtonText>Order Now!</ButtonText>
  </Button>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Ok since you need to add styles to the Link so that the `position: absolute` works on the Button, you're going to have to wrap the `<Link>` in something that you can position. You can do this by wrapping it in something like a `<p>` or a `<div>`.

Let's say you wrap it in a `<div>` now you can set `position: relative` and decide where that is, and then your button will be positioned based on the position of the Link.

Additionally, I think you could just position your button not `absolute` and fiddle with where it is placed, but I gather that's not the approach you wanna take.

Comment: Cheers that is a great workaround does work perfect - put Mosh's answer as the ticked answer though because I preferred adding style onto <Link> tag as less code